# What is the hotkey for command in Pyautogui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyautogui

I am messing around with PyAutoGUI, and I am learning about the `hotkey` function. I want it to press Command+R, but I can't find the keyword (like `control` becomes `ctrl`). What is it?

I am using Pycharm. I am fully aware that this would lead to a forever loop.

I am learning from [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mouse-keyboard-automation-using-python/).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The keyword for command is just `command`.

So `pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'r')` should work fine.

[Documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys)

Comment: Oh! I actually saw that but my eyes died before I got to the end. Why such fine print?!?!?

Comment: FWIW, most browsers have some way of searching for a string, so you could have searched for "command" and found it fairly quickly.

Comment: Yeah I know I found it I just thought it wouldn't be in the documentation not sure why